# Are Actionable notifications in iOS only local notifications or they can be sent from the server as well?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Are *Actionable notifications* in iOS only local notifications, or can they be sent from the server?

I'm interested in adding an actionable notification with two buttons in the app. I read the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/declaring_your_actionable_notification_types) and I'm not clear if this type of notification can only be only local notification or if they can be sent from the server as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked documentation even gives an example of how to do it. So yes, you can create actionable notifications from remote (push) notifications. Just send along the category identifier in the aps dictionary of the notification payload as described in the docs:

```
{
  “aps” : {
    “category” : “MEETING_INVITATION”
    “alert” : {
      “title” : “Weekly Staff Meeting”
      “body” : “Every Tuesday at 2pm”
    },
  },
  “MEETING_ID” : “123456789”,
  “USER_ID” : “ABCD1234”
}
```

And then it will show the actions associated to that category.